# Wordpress - Plugin translation not working

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

My plugin name is `eventcal`.Textdomain is `eventcal`. I have a language pack in `/languages/` folder - `eventcal-pt_BR.po` and `eventcal-pt_BR.mo`. I have added plugin textdomain function

```
public static function eventcalLoadTextdomain() {
  load_plugin_textdomain( 'eventcal', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}

// in __constructor()
add_action( 'init', array(self::getInstance(), 'eventcalLoadTextdomain' ));
```

but its not working when i am changing my site language to `portugese( Brazil )`

Nothing is changing.everything is in english. How can i check plugin textdomain is working or not??

I also tried `get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );` but not working

Comment: Are you using [translation strings in your plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)? `echo esc_html__( 'Blog Options', 'eventcal' );`

Comment: @admcfajn yesss

Comment: & you're sure that `dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ` points to the correct folder? Sometimes the IA of plugin can throw that off.

Comment: @admcfajn not sure about that.How can i make sure?

Comment: `echo dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages'; exit;`

Comment: @admcfajn i dont see any output :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186084/discussion-between-admcfajn-and-tick-twitch).